# Need sql query to get price by sku in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, sql

```
<?php
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
 var_dump($results);
```

i need sql query for get product price by sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento is saved Product price at  `catalog_product_index_price` and 
Here magento is saved  customer group wise products price fields.So you need `to inner join with this table.But is give you multiple rows for a products.By default it take one row when customer is not logged-in.`

1. Product ID
2. Customer Group ID
3. Website ID
4. Tax Class ID
5. Price Final
6. Price Min
7. Price Max
8. Price Tier
9. Price Group price

See table:

[image]

**Here the Query:**

```
    SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, 

`price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, 

LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS 
`minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, 
`price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN 
`catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
 price_index.website_id = '0' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
```

Here i have put customer group id and its 0  for getting on a records product price

Answer (score 1):

Here is the SQL, of course you can change it with NESTED SELECTS:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $resource->getTableName('catalog/product') . " p
INNER JOIN " . $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " ped ON p.entity_id = ped.entity_id
INNER JOIN " . $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute') . " ea ON ea.attribute_id = ped.attribute_id
INNER JOIN " . $resource->getTableName('eav/entity_type') . " eet ON eet.entity_type_id = ped.entity_type_id
WHERE p.sku = 'test' AND ea.attribute_code = 'price' AND eet.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'";
```

You have to change 'test' with your own SKU. To get only the price here is the code:

```
$result = $readConnection->fetchRow($query);
echo $result['value'];
```